# Detecting substring between strings with special characters

Tags: python, string, special-characters

I have 6 types of strings (after performing `strip()` on them):

```
string_1= 'This is a \'working draft\' sequence. It currently consists of 10 contigs. Gaps between the contigsare represented as runs of N. The order of the piecesis believed to be correct as given, however the sizesof the gaps between them are based on estimates that haveprovided by the submittor.This sequence will be replacedby the finished sequence as soon as it is available andthe accession number will be preserved.\n???UPDATE FROM "This record contains 83 individual sequencing reads that have not been assembled intocontigs. Runs of N are used to separate the readsand the order in which they appear is completelyarbitrary. Low-pass sequence sampling is useful foridentifying clones that may be gene-rich and allowsoverlap relationships among clones to be deduced.However, it should not be assumed that this clonewill be sequenced to completion. In the event thatthe record is updated, the accession number willbe preserved."???'

string_2= '???INSERT information???\n\nPlasmid; n/a; 100% of reads'

string_3= '???INSERT information???\n\ngap of      100 bp'

string_x= "This is a 'working draft' sequence. It currently consists of 10 contigs. Gaps between the contigsare represented as runs of N. The order of the piecesis believed to be correct as given, however the sizesof the gaps between them are based on estimates that haveprovided by the submittor.This sequence will be replacedby the finished sequence as soon as it is available andthe accession number will be preserved."

string_y= 'Plasmid; n/a; 100% of reads'

string_z= 'gap of      100 bp'
```

I am trying to make it so that:

```
if string_x in string_1:
    print("true")

if string_y in string_2:
    print("true")

if string_z in string_3:
    print("true")
```

However, this would not work even if I strip all the strings.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work as expected?

Comment: It seems to work (it prints `true` in all cases), unless you want it not to print `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to shape your strings to one format

```
string_1 = ''.join([x for x in string_1  if x.isalpha() or x == ' '])
string_x = ''.join([x for x in string_x  if x.isalpha() or x == ' '])
```

Comment: And then compare strings to each other

Answer (score 2):

First you need to understand what `str.strip()` method does. It returns a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed.

Syntax : `str. strip([chars])`

Example 1

```
>>> '   spacious   '.strip()
'spacious'
>>> "AABAA".strip("A")
'B'
>>> "ABBA".strip("AB")
''
>>> "ABCABBA".strip("AB")
'C'
```

Example 2

```
>>> 'www.example.com'.strip('cmowz.') # this example extracts web address
'example'
```

For more you can read the [Official Documentation.](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html#example-1)